# What does "develop attitudes" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Kindly explain what "develop attitudes" means in this context of the [following passage](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/276428/Dispelling_some_myths_about_the_autistic_wunderkind_programmer.php):

> In the ensuing outrage, a PowerPoint presentation written by St. John surfaced which included a slide in which he referred to engineers with Asperger syndrome as being "the holy grail" of hires. "They work like machines," he wrote, "don’t engage in politics, don’t ***develop attitudes*** and never change jobs."

I searched the definition of "Attitude" and came up to 2 options:
1) autist people don't express their attitude to work
2) don't try to affect opinion of other people in a team about something

Comment: Text quotes should be set in block. Use [shift]> at leading character of paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

To "develop attitudes" (in the social sense of the word) is to develop *bad* attitudes.

Everyone has attitudes, but it is (usually) the bad ones that get noticed.

He has an "attitude" is a pejorative. And "autistic" people don't "develop attitudes" is in the context of they don't have other bad qualities like laziness and "politicking."